# What happens if an exception occurs within a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, exception, objective-c-blocks

I was just trying to understand what would happen if an exception occurs within a block? where will it be thrown as it runs on a separate thread.

also can some one suggest me the better implementation of the following two options?

```
@try{

[self performBlock^{
some code 
}];

}
@catch (NSException*e) {
}
```

or

```
[self performBlock^{
@try{
some code 
}
@catch (NSException*e) {
}
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #2, it obviously catches the exception in the code.

For #1, it depends on what this `performBlock:` method does. Try blocks catch exceptions that happen further down the stack, i.e. synchronous function calls. So if `performBlock:` calls its block synchronously, exceptions there will be caught by the try block. But if it calls it asynchronously, then exceptions there will not be caught by the try block, because when the block is executed, the try block is not in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are typically tied to the thread where they occur, so #2 is a more appropriate way of catching such an exception.

However, in the real world of Objective C or Swift, you really don't want to be catching exceptions at all. It's tempting to think of the Apple runtimes like Java or C# since exceptions are available in the languages; however, exceptions should rarely be used to communicate errors since they are just not safe. Under ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) exceptions can leave unreleased memory - which is a fairly undesirable problem.

Instead, use NSError output parameters. Check the errors religiously.

You're probably thinking this is lame - and it is - but's that just how it works.

Comment: so if an exception arises within a block, Then It cant be caught using #1? or is it just #2 makes more sense?